# Select distinct(columnName) from a table having COALESCE

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this with many records. for example:

```
   HREFTopic                       PopularTopic                  LastModifiedTime
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 //twitter.com/search?q=%23Happy    #Happy St. Patrick's Day    2015-03-17 19:57:18.000
 //twitter.com/search?q=%23Happy    #Happy St. Patrick's Day    2015-03-17 18:57:17.000
 //twitter.com/search?q=%23HappyV   #Happy Valentines Day   2015-03-17 17:57:15.000
```

This is my stored procedure

```
 declare @abc nvarchar(max)  
 declare @SearchKey nvarchar(max) 
 select @SearchKey ='Happy'
 select top 10   @abc =  COALESCE(@abc + '','') + '<li>' + '<a class="z" href="' +'../q.aspx?q=' + @SearchKey + '">' + (PopularTopic)  + '</a></li>' + char(10) + char(13)      
 from PopularTrends  where HREFTopic like    '%'+ @SearchKey +'%'   order by LastModifiedTime desc   

 select @abc
```

and the output is (@abc) =

```
 <li><a class="z" href="../q.aspx?q=Happy">Happy St. Patrick's Day</a></li>
 <li><a class="z" href="../q.aspx?q=HappyV">Happy Valentines Day  </a></li> 
 <li><a class="z" href="../q.aspx?q=Happy">Happy St. Patrick's Day</a></li> 
 <li><a class="z" href="../q.aspx?q=Happy">Happy St. Patrick's Day</a></li> 
 <li><a class="z" href="../q.aspx?q=Happy">Happy St. Patrick's Day</a></li>
 <li><a class="z" href="../q.aspx?q=Happy">Happy St. Patrick's Day</a></li>
 <li><a class="z" href="../q.aspx?q=Happy">Happy St. Patrick's Day</a></li>
```

but I need only distinct(PopularTopic) order by LastModifiedTime and I expect the result  to be :

```
 <li><a class="z" href="../q.aspx?q=Happy">Happy St. Patrick's Day</a></li>
 <li><a class="z" href="../q.aspx?q=HappyV">Happy Valentines Day  </a></li>
```

I am not able to get the distinct(PopularTopic), rather I get all the records.
Can some one help me with getting the right query.

Comment: What happens if you put the word "DISTINCT" after "top 10"?   If that doesn't work, try GROUP BY PopularTopic

Comment: syntax error by putting the word distinct after top10 and group by gives error.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do it, and it's better to learn to use FOR XML PATH for string concatenation than the undocumented variable-building process you were using.   There are lots of examples on the internet.

```
WITH cte AS (
 select top 10 PopularTopic, MAX(LastModifiedTime) AS LMT
 from PopularTrends  
 where HREFTopic like '%'+ @SearchKey +'%'  
 GROUP BY PopularTopic 
 order by LMT desc   
)
SELECT 
 (
  SELECT '<li><a class="z" href="../q.aspx?q='+@SearchKey+'">' + PopularTopic + '</a></li>' + char(10) + char(13)               
  FROM cte
  FOR XML PATH(''), root('h'), type
 ).value('/h[1]','varchar(max)')
```

And, for what it's worth, you'd get better overall performance if you just returned the top 10 PopularTopics from the database and handled the list-building in your application layer.

Comment: It works perfectly. thanks-----I have more than 150000 records and this search key processing takes time. I am getting the result only after 4 seconds. I am unsure how to make it less than a second.

Comment: There is not much you can do to speed up a LIKE %% search because it can't use indexes.   4 seconds for 150000 records is actually pretty good for this kind of search.   You might be able to improve performance by using FULL TEXT INDEXING.

Comment: I have installed the full text search. Now how should I change the query accordingly? Will the same query work?

Comment: I've never used full text search, but no I think you have to change the query to use it.   Look for examples on the web.   I think it uses a CONTAINS keyword, maybe.